# Exactly n numbers in a row

Tags: java

I am solving a task, but stuck in one moment with input numbers.

```
Input example:

//n and k

3 2

// inputing random n numbers (this time 3 numbers)
2 3 4
```

In the first line I have 2 digits (n and k seperated by space). In the second line I need to input n numbers (which is given in the fist line) seperated by space . How can I solve this? This is what I have now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String  lines = br.readLine();
        String[] strs = lines.trim().split("\\s+");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(strs[0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(strs[1]);

//here starts my problem
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            numbers.add(number);
        }

    }
```

I managed to take the first two digits in first line. But I couldn't solve taking n digits of the second line. I need it to be int. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Perhaps use a `Scanner` instead, and use `Scanner.nextInt()` to take a single int.

Comment: @AndyTurner Is there a good example with scanner?

Comment: Because `br.readLine()` reads in the whole line, in the 2nd iteration of the loop I think you will have gone through all the ints already. You probably want to read only an int instead of the whole line. Or you could parse the line yourself like you did in the first section.

Comment: @xdhmoore When I input n digits in second line, it throws me Exception

Comment: I would imagine it throws an exception because `br.readline()` returns null?  Your loop is set to `n` iterations, but you are using up all `n` items in the first iteration by reading in the whole line. Here are the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for using a Scanner, as @AndyTurner suggested.

Comment: @xdhmoore Yes, I am using all n iterations. Now I see the problem. Thanks for docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a similar approach to that you used for reading and processing the first line.

```
String  line = br.readLine();
String[] strs = line.trim().split("\\s+");
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(strs[ i ]);
    numbers.add(number);
}
```